# Syncfusion WinRT: Exception on code working in version 12.2.0.36 that now doesn't work on version 13.1.0.21

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, syncfusion

I asked this on syncfusion foruns, but i figured i would give it a try here also

I worked on a project some time ago, that used Syncfusion for WinRT version 12.2.0.36
it had some pdf manipulation, such as adding images to the pdf. After some effort it was working and the part of the code was something like this

```
//...
foreach (var image in this.images)   //image is type Windows.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Image
            {
                var bitmap = image.Source as ImageSource;
                var index = bitmaps.IndexOf(bitmap);
                var signature = signatures.ElementAt(index);
                var bytes = await signature.Data.EncodePngToJpeg();  //returns bytes of png image converted to jpg


                PdfImage pdfImage;
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    pdfImage = PdfImage.FromStream(memoryStream);
                }


        var transform = image.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

                var x = (image.Margin.Left + transform.TranslateX + horizontalOffset) * 100 / pdfViewer.Zoom - 10;
                var y = (image.Margin.Top + transform.TranslateY + verticalOffset) * 100 / pdfViewer.Zoom - 10;

                var firstPage = pdfDocument.Pages[pdfViewer.PageNumber - 1];
                var pageHeight = firstPage.Size.Height;
                var pageWidth = firstPage.Size.Width;

                var selpage = pdfViewer.PageNumber;

                var pagn = selpage - 1;
                if (pagn < 0)
                    pagn = 0;

                var ss = pdfViewer.GetDescendantsOfType<ScrollViewer>();
                var hh = ss.ElementAt(3);
                float VertOff = (float)hh.VerticalOffset;
                float VertOff2 = (VertOff * 100 / pdfViewer.Zoom) - ((pagn) * (pageHeight * 1.325f));


                var page = pdfDocument.Pages[pagn];
                var graphics = page.Graphics;

                var width = image.Width;
                var height = image.Height;

                //float fWidth = (float)width;
                //float fHeight = (float)height;
                fWidth = 165f * 0.50f;
                fHeight = 110f * 0.50f;

                graphics.ScaleTransform(0.75f, 0.75f);
                graphics.DrawImage(pdfImage, (float)x, (float)y + VertOff2, fWidth, fHeight);   // <-- exception is here 

            }
```

what this did was adding a list of images to a pdf document in specific places, and after this code i would save and upload.

then i installed the WinRT trial version (13.1.0.21) and i started to get this exception

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in Syncfusion.Pdf.WinRT.DLL System.NullReferenceException' :
>   {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

with this StackTrace:

> at Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics.PdfBitmap.SetColorSpace()    at
>   Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics.PdfBitmap.Save()    at
>   Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics.PdfGraphics.DrawImage(PdfImage image, Single
>   x, Single y, Single width, Single height)    at
>   Gapp_metro.Pages.PdfPage.d__25.MoveNext()

Did anything changed between versions that might be giving me an error?
Or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Essential PDF Winrt supports the following image formats.
1. Jpeg
2. PNG
3. Tiff
4. Gif

Please try the PNG image without convert it to jpeg, I have attached the sample project for your reference, Please try this and let me know the result.

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/118851/InsertingImage613405857.zip

Regards,

Karthikeyan.C

Comment: i figured it out, the problem was this line:   PdfImage pdfImage;